# Element type "EditText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to the android app development and I am trying to build a simple interface but it shows me the following error `Element type "EditText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: close your edit text

Comment: The error message cannot be any more easy to understand dude, Element type "EditText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Comment: Good work @Sumit Sharma you have given close tag to others views like Button and LinearLayout yet Surprisingly not given to EditText very good achievement.

Answer (score 6):

Not an Android freak but, being an xml user your edittext code might be

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />  <--
```

Missing the end tag. You have to add `/>` just like you did for Button below.